# Using two USB wifi adapters as one single WAP (wireless access point)

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, hostapd

I'm wondering if this is possible or anyone has done this.
I'm building a linux router/WAP for my house, I'm not completly sold on the distro yet probably going to use either: openWRT/DD-WRT x86, Pfsense/OPNsense, zeroshell or at the moment I think I'm actually leaning towards just using a full distro like Kali, Ubuntu or Debian and setting up all the packages/services I need (probably hostapd)

Anyway

I have a heap of USB wifi adapters including a **2 TP-Link TL-WN722N USB** adapters, which have proven useful in the past for various wifi tasks on kali, so I know they are capable adapters and support station mode etc.

What I am wondering is if there are any tools or whatnot that would allow me to sort of **bridge the two** to **'load balance'** of sorts **both adapters to be the access point** for my DIY router/AP ?

I know I could simply run two instances of hostapd, two different channels broadcasting the same SSID and.. the clients would just jump from one to the other depending on signal strength but I would prefer something more elegent than that, maybe some sort of service that handled the hand over etc... or even better something that perhaps split the transmission packets between the two making each handle half the traffic... 
I'm thinking the later is probably certainly not possible without some fairly dedicated services/hardware.
*P.S I have a few decent external antennas I plan on attaching both have a few meters/feet of coax cable so I can place them a fair away from each other to improve range*

As always, any insight and advice, will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.
Josh

Comment: All I'd be aware of is usb adaptors generally have very small/short anntenna so might not be ideal for a AP.

Comment: I have two TL-ANT2409A 9DBi antennas attached to each dongle.